# Access to specific raw with partial information using Regex on Bigtable

Tags: javascript, regex, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm working with Google BigTable. I would like to use the convertToRegExpString method to access at specific Row Key having partial information.

I have a row key like this: 
"AAAAA&BBBBB&CCCCC&DDDDD"

I should pass to the method a regex that specifies first two keys (AAAAA&BBBBB) and the last one (DDDDD), bypassing the third value. Consider that the third value has a variable length and it can be compose by characters and numbers.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, what's the question exactly? If you're wondering how to compose this regex, I believe it would be something like AAAAA&BBBBB&[^&]+&DDDDD

Comment: Yep you get the point! If this work i'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for this should be something like AAAAA&BBBBB&[^&]+&DDDDD

It looks for your first two fields AAAAA and BBBBB with delimiters, then at least one non-delimiter character (the [^&] is an inverted character class and the + means "at least one"), and finally a delimiter and your last field DDDDD.